# How to plot a circle at the endpoint of a quiver plot in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a dataframe consisting of a set of actual positions for X and Y and their target positions and i have done the quiver plot for the following. Now I need to plot a circle at the end point of the quiver plot using the error ('distance' value from the dataframe) as the diameter. It would be really helpful if someone could guide me how to go about it.

The dataframe looks like this : (Only the first 10 rows are added here)

```
rTargetPosX  rTargetPosY  Actual_PositionX Actual_PositionY  Distance 
27.284047    1.297492     27.321201        1.373254          0.186804
27.275899    26.338611    27.314813        26.376698         0.176827
27.270484    51.341236    27.295110        51.420660         0.185890
27.271348    76.357327    27.308524        76.430147         0.198785
27.272140    101.359197   27.337727        101.411670        0.194511
27.272670    126.359012   27.278433        126.448553        0.191449
57.271197    1.366512     57.347794        1.316646          0.222369
57.277112    26.326415    57.295121        26.379356         0.163582
57.272157    51.333405    57.320267        51.358652         0.199854
57.273236    76.339232    57.308497        76.397345         0.169904
57.276851    101.347857   57.324807        101.420733        0.196919
```

The code for what I have done so far and the result is given below:

```
fig, ax =plt.subplots()
for i in range(0,len(df_quiver)):
    x = df_quiver.iloc[i][0]

    y = df_quiver.iloc[i][1]

    u = df_quiver.iloc[i][2]
    v = df_quiver.iloc[i][3]
    plt.quiver([x],[y],u,v,width=0.003)

plt.show()
```

The output of the code gave the following:
[The output quiver plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuCeR.png)

Please let me know how I can plot a circle at the end of the plot using the 'distance' value from the dataframe as a diameter.

P.S : I am unable to add the plot as a picture because I am new to stackoverflow and don't have enough reputations.

Comment: What about using [`matplotlib.patches.Circle`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Circle.html?highlight=circle#matplotlib-patches-circle)? You can easily use your `Distance` column to set the radius. You did not specify "where" you want to draw: "at the end of the plot" is not very clear...

Comment: Hi. Sorry that I was not clear before. I want to draw the circle at the tip of each of the arrow in the quiver plot. I did try using matplotlib.patches.Circle but it is always plotting the circle at the starting point of the arrow whereas my requirement is at the tip of the arrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take care of two things to achieve this.

- First, you have to set the `scale` and `scale_units` of you quiver plot to be able to compute the coordinate of the end of the arrow. Without it, Matplotlib use an autoscaling, making the computation impossible.
- Then, you have to [set the aspect ratio](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect) of your axes to be able to draw circular circles (see [demo](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/axis_equal_demo.html)). Without this, I was not able to put the circles at the right y coordinate and to make them circular.

Here is an example code:

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd


def main():
    df_quiver = pd.DataFrame(
        [[27.284047, 1.297492, 27.321201, 1.373254, 0.186804],
         [27.275899, 26.338611, 27.314813, 26.376698, 0.176827],
         [27.270484, 51.341236, 27.295110, 51.420660, 0.185890],
         [27.271348, 76.357327, 27.308524, 76.430147, 0.198785],
         [27.272140, 101.359197, 27.337727, 101.411670, 0.194511],
         [27.272670, 126.359012, 27.278433, 126.448553, 0.191449],
         [57.271197, 1.366512, 57.347794, 1.316646, 0.222369],
         [57.277112, 26.326415, 57.295121, 26.379356, 0.163582],
         [57.272157, 51.333405, 57.320267, 51.358652, 0.199854],
         [57.273236, 76.339232, 57.308497, 76.397345, 0.169904],
         [57.276851, 101.347857, 57.324807, 101.420733, 0.196919]],
        columns = ["rTargetPosX", "rTargetPosY", "Actual_PositionX", "Actual_PositionY", "Distance"]
    )

    scale = 2
    fig, axs =plt.subplots(2, 1)
    axs[0].set_title("Aspect ratio: default")
    axs[1].axis('equal')
    axs[1].set_title("Aspect ratio: 'equal'")
    axs[0].quiver(
        df_quiver["rTargetPosX"],
        df_quiver["rTargetPosY"],
        df_quiver["Actual_PositionX"],
        df_quiver["Actual_PositionY"],
        width=0.003,
        scale_units="x",
        scale=scale
    )
    axs[1].quiver(
        df_quiver["rTargetPosX"],
        df_quiver["rTargetPosY"],
        df_quiver["Actual_PositionX"],
        df_quiver["Actual_PositionY"],
        width=0.003,
        scale_units="x",
        scale=scale
    )
    for _, sample in df_quiver.iterrows():
        x = sample["rTargetPosX"] + sample["Actual_PositionX"] / scale
        y = sample["rTargetPosY"] + sample["Actual_PositionY"] / scale
        axs[0].add_patch(mpl.patches.Circle(
            (x, y), sample["Distance"] * 10,
            alpha=0.7, zorder=-1
        ))
        axs[1].add_patch(mpl.patches.Circle(
            (x, y), sample["Distance"] * 10,
            alpha=0.7, zorder=-1
        ))


    plt.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And the resulting plot:

[image: Rendering of the above code]

Comment: Hi. Thank you so much. This looks exactly like what I want to achieve. Will give it a try.